# How to get the map object from div in GWT

Tags: gwt, google-maps-api-3, jsni

I am trying to get the map type from a map in GWT using JSNI. I want to call `map.getCurrentMapType().getName()` but I dont know how to get the map object from the div `#map_canvas`.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Let us assume that the division (map object) you want to access is in the DOM and has an id (map_canvas), you can access  as follows:

```
Document.get().getElementById("map_canvas")
```

from java, or

```
$doc.getElementById("map_canvas")
```

from javascript :)